# $\check{R}$ matrix acting on $2$ out of $m$ vector spaces

Tags: representation-theory, integrable-systems

We know that $\check{R} \in \operatorname{End}(V \otimes V)$ is a solution of Yang-Baxter equation:

$$
\check{R}_{23} \check{R}_{12} \check{R}_{23}=\check{R}_{12}\check{R}_{23} \check{R}_{12}
$$
where $\check{R}_{a,b}$ act on 2 out of 3 vector spaces. Can we generalize this to $m$ copies of vector spaces? For example, consider $\check{R}_{a,b} \in \operatorname{End}(V^{(m)})$, where $V^{(m)} := V^{\otimes m}$. Is $\check{R}_{i,i+1}$ a solution of Yang-Baxter equation:

$$\check{R}_{i,i+1} \check{R}_{i-1,i} \check{R}_{i,i+1}=\check{R}_{i-1,i}\check{R}_{i,i+1} \check{R}_{i-1,i}$$
where $1 \leq i \leq m-1$?

Comment: Yes, except that it holds for $1<i \leq m$ if the subscripts are as in the displayed equation. This follows immediately from the meaning of the subscripts (the operators act by the identity on all other spaces).